# The linker link, but the executable ask for another dll

Tags: dll, linker

I'm using mingw. I have a dll named gtksourceview-3.0-1.dll, my program is compiled without problem, the linker doesn't report any error, but when I lauch the program, it is asking for another dll: gtksourceview-3.0-0.dll.

When I compile with g++, I pass as argument: -lgtksourceview-3.0. Why my program is searching for the wrong dll ? How to tell my program to use the right dll ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved, there was a error in Makefile, in LDFLAGS a "-L/directory/lib", refering to a /lib directory that contain libgtksourceview-3.0.dll.a and libgtksourceview-3.0.la corresponding to the wrong dll.